# KeystoneJS signin

Tags: signing, keystonejs

I am creating a keystone project and I need to provide allow or not allow users to access using the keystone signin. However, I found that keystoneJS sends a form data with email, password and csrf. This csrf is given to the user when he access to the login page.

Nevertheless, what I need to do is to comunicate externally to login the user, by using an API. How can I generate the _csrf? Is there another way then generate two requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Sericaia, you didn't include any code or specifics on how you intend to implement your login page, so my answer will be a little vague.

Keystone has an internal API for handling CSRF token creation and validation. I don't think it's documented, but here's a gist of how it works.

In your route handler you can create a CSRF token key/value pair that you can then inject into your view locals and then use in your view template. You can do it manually like this.

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  var keystone = require('keystone');
  var csrfTokenKey = keystone.security.csrf.TOKEN_KEY;
  var csrfTokenValue = keystone.security.csrf.getToken(req, res);

  res.render('login', {
    csrfTokenKey: csrfTokenKey, 
    csrfTokenValue: csrfTokenValue
  });
});
```

Or you can use provided middleware.

```
// the middleware will automatically inject the CSRF token 
// into res.locals[keystone.security.csrf.LOCAL_KEY]
app.get('/login', keystone.security.csrf.middleware.init, function(req, res) {
    ...
});
```

You can also validate the CSRF token received from the client. You can do it manually as follows:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  if (keystone.security.csrf.validate(req)) {
    // CSRF is valid 
    ...
  } else {
    // CSRF is not valid
    ...
  }

});
```

Or you can use the provided middleware.

```
// the middleware will return 403 status with "CSRF token mismatch"
// of there's a error validating the CSRF token received
app.post('/login', keystone.security.csrf.middleware.validate, function(req, res) {
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, I think it helped.. I've made my custom get/post login page

Comment: That's awesome! Hope you also get to do the PR for the signup page on `generator-keystone`. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't had time for it :/

Comment: I am acessing keystone from an external source (Unity project) and when the user is logged in, I receive the set-cookie header. However, when I subsequently send a request with the cookie, req.user is undefined. Ideias?

Comment: @Sericaia, would you mind opening another question and adding code so I can take a look at it?