# KeystoneJS Signup via Rest request

Tags: keystonejs

Using sydjs as book to get everything working

I'm trying to signup users via POST request via api:

/api/app/signup-email

Whenever I send data with only email&pass - everything works. If I try to add name parameter - it always fails. 
Registration on front-end works as it should

Sending data as:

```
let parameters = [
            "email": "\(email)",
            "password": "\(password)",
            "name": [
                "first": "\(firstname)",
                "last": "\(lastname)"
            ]   
        ]
```

Maybe anyone has any idea why it doesn't work with name included? Thx.

Comment: You should send an object instead of an array when passing such parameters: use { } these braces instead of [ ]

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because login request in Keystone need a _CSRF token validation, you need to provide it as parameter.

One example is first make a GET request to your login page (The CSRF Token will be in the HEADER response), save it and then make your login request passing the CSRF token obtained in the previous request.

This will be helpful [KeystoneJS signin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240757/keystonejs-signin)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a login against the REST-API of keystone (v4.0.0-beta.5). On the client-side I chose [npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). I enabled request's cookie-functionality (config option `request.defaults({ jar: true });`).

The login consisted of two separate-requests:

1. A simple GET-request against: https://www.yourkeystoneapp.com/keystone/session/signin

   - npm request will receive a cookie containing the CSRF token. There is nothing else you need to do with it. npm request will use the received cookie for all subsequent http-requests.
2. A POST-request containing a simple JSON body with your credentials:

   ```
   {
     email: 'user@yourkeystoneapp.com',
     password: 'yourpassword'
   }
   ```
3. The POST-request will be answered by Keystone with a valid user-object, if the credentials were correct.
4. All subsequent http-requests will be part of a valid session, as long as the CSRF-token is valid.

Code examples:

```
// enable cookies
request.defaults({
  jar: true
});

// first request to obtain the cookie
request('https://www.yourkeystoneapp.com/signin', {/* some options */});

// second request to POST your credentials
var loginOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.yourkeystoneapp.come/api/session/signin',
  headers: {
   'content-type': 'application/json',
   'accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'user@yourkeystoneapp.com',
    password: 'yourpassword
  })
};

// issue POST request.
request(loginOptions);

// You are now logged in
```

If you are using  `npm request`, as I did, you have to take a couple of measures to sync the requests you issue, as `npm request` works asynchronously. Making use of `npm request`'s API and its callback-functions is mandatory.